# Ubuntu 14.04 cannot detect GTX 850M nvidia driver after installation

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

The following are what I did:

1. sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic

Except it reported that it cannot locate dkms.conf, everything goes well.

2. reboot
3. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
4. sudo apt-get update
5. sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
6. reboot

After that, I can find an application called "NVIDIA X Server Settings" in my application list, and everything looks normal in it. It can even show the tempature of my GPU.

But sudo lshw -C display still cannot show my nvidia GTX 850M (I have already enabled NVIDIA):

```
*-display
   description: 3D controller
   product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:55 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:52 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

EDIT:

I am not sure is there any problem in my question, I think maybe I need describe what I expect in more details. I think if the driver is installed successfully, after I sudo lshw -C display, the "VGA compatible controller" should also be nvidia one, but now it still is Intel Integrated one.

If I am correct, does anyone can tell me what should I do to make the VGA compatible controller to nvidia one. If I am wrong, how could I know whether my naughty GPU is running or not. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in 14.04 the only way to use the nvidia was to turn off the Intel card in the bios. There should be a disable option in there. From there, I suggest doing a re-install of ubuntu (if you have only just installed it) and install the nvidia drivers from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your constructive suggestion. Actually I have installed this 14.04 LTS for a long time and re-installing currently may not be very practical since I am still using my Ubuntu for some tasks and I also don't want to disable the Intel card, because I still want to use it sometimes for power saving.